# Points on a circle geometry

Tags: ios, math

[image]

I want to implement the following:

I have two touchable objects on a circle.

If I touch and move the object in the red box, I want the object on the left to move correspondingly along the blue circle - as if it were being pulled after the first object by a a transparent rope.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, the button will be on se same axsis of the buttonFinger. If you want a different one, add a offset to `touchAngle`:

```
float    centerX; //Center of your Circle on X
float    centerY; //Center of your Circle on Y
float  touchAngle; //Angle of the touch
int    touchHash;
XxX    button; //Your "button" to be kept in the bluecircle
XxX    buttonFinger; //Your "button" that follow your finger

int    maxRadius; //The maximum radius: from center to the end of the blue circle
int    minRadius; //The minimum radius: from center to the beginning of the blue circle
CGRect CGRectPantone; //The CGRect of your available touch zone

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
     for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
     {
         CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
         if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectPantone, touchLocation))
         {
            touchHash = [touch hash];
            buttonFinger.center = touchLocation;
         }
      }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
    {           
    if ([touch hash] == touchHash)
    {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectPantone, touchLocation))
        {
            buttonFinger.center = touchLocation;
            float dx = centerX - (float)touchLocation.x;
            float dy = centerY - (float)touchLocation.y;
            touchAngle = -atan2f(dx, dy)+(M_PI/2.0);

            button.center = CGPointMake(centerX-((minRadius+(maxRadius-minRadius)/2.0)*cosf(touchAngle)), centerY-((minRadius+(maxRadius-minRadius)/2.0)*sinf(touchAngle)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this depends on the angle. In the picture, for instance, the first button would be at an angle of `0` degrees in the circle while the second button would be at `270` degrees. You would have to measure the angle `alpha` of the first button after movement and rotate the second button to the position `270 + alpha mod 360`.